# Redirecting to another website with query params and can't be accessed in Next.js for using in React Native

Tags: react-native, next.js

I need to use a payment gateway. After payment is done, it redirects with some query params to a callback URL which is my declared website URL. But When I check `useRouter` and even `URLSearchParams`, they are `undefined` or `null` when I need to use **Deep Linking** to open the mobile application with the query params above.

How can I do that?

Comment: In case you are using rect-navigation you could use by defining NavigationContainer linking property (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out as I said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77112516/getting-query-params-doesnt-work-with-android-emulator) question, Android emulator can't work well with query params in Next.js 13 and I attached a device for running the application and it works well.