# Getting query params doesn't work with Android emulator

Tags: next.js

Please check this link out:

https://gymtracker.ir/tuitionPayment?trans_id=EXAMPLE&id_get=EXAMPLE

Without `trans_id` or `id_get` query params, `null` is returned.

```js
export default function TuitionPayment() {
  const [transId, setTransId] = useState(null);
  const [idGet, setIdGet] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    setTransId(searchParams.get("trans_id"));
    setIdGet(searchParams.get("id_get"));
  }, []);

  if (!transId || !idGet) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
        <Link
          href={`gymtracker://tuition/${transId}/${idGet}`}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
        >
          <Box
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "#66A182",
              py: 1,
              px: 2,
              color: "#fff",
              borderRadius: 1,
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">Return to Application</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

But in Android emulator, it always return `null` and doesn't show anything even along with the needed query params.

What's the problem?

I'm using Next.js 13.4.4 with `pages` folder.

Comment: Which android emulator are you using?

Comment: @RobinThomas Android Studio

Comment: What is the value of `params` (in the code from question) within the emulator?

Comment: @RobinThomas How should I check `console.log` in emulator? :)

Comment: Change the `window.location.search` to `document.location.search` and check if it works.

Comment: @RobinThomas I'll inform you Thomas.

Comment: @RobinThomas No it didn't. It returns `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Android emulator doesn't work well with query params with Next.js 13.
I decided to use a device for running the application and it works well with the website.